# What happens with the GCM token when two users are sharing one device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If my android application registers with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), my user receives a token that I send to my application server and it connects it to that user.

What happens if the user logs out of the app, and another user logs in. Are they going to use the same token? Will they receive the another user's push notifications?

Comment: the user doesn't "receive a token" the token is a device token relating to the device and the app. If you do a fresh install of your app you will probably see the token has refreshed and changed, you need to unregister every time a user logs out and then have them register every time they login

Comment: so if I want to have multiple users on the same device, I should delete the current token from the server upon log out, and submit a new one upon log in, right?

Comment: Sorry not from the server, only from server when you try to send to it - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is unregister every time a user logs out. and register when they login.

You can call `gcm.unregister();` when they logout.

Its not like you can have two users logged in on the same device at the same time so i don't think you need to do anything too fancy. When you unregister the token it will still be in your list of tokens to send to so when google tells you it failed to send to that token you need to remove it from your table. You probably already do this.

Comment: I am the android app developer, and our app server is being developed by another guy. Should I tell him to collect an array of user tokens and try to send the push notifications to all of them, or should I tell him to create an API Endpoint for removing a GCM token (or do it automatically at log out)

Comment: standard procedure would be to send each token to the server, store all of them in a table. Send to all of them , if for any reason any of them fail then remove them from the table. You shouldn't need to remove them in any other situation. by unregistering a token with GCM will tell google its not registered and next time you send to it you will get a reply back from google saying it failed to send the token is not registered, at which point your guy can remove it :-)

Comment: @J.K. also keep in mind that both google and iOS don't like it when apps register multiple times in quick succession so keep that in mind with your testing and implementation.